# How to set CSS for embedded PDF viewer with CSP enabled

Tags: css, pdf, content-security-policy

I got the following problem:
Having set

```
Content-Security-Policy style-src 'self'
```

within .htacess file, chrome complains in the developer console when displaying PDF files linked like `<a href="file.pdf">`.

```
Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following
Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Either the
'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-[deleted]'), or a nonce
('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

I can also see that chrome applies some css to the PDF display:

```
element.style {
background-color: rgb(38,38,38);
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0;
}
```

Of course, the easy way would be to just change the CSP settings in .htaccess to

```
Content-Security-Policy style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'
```

but that would damage security. Also I hesitate to give a hash to code I can not control.
So the question is:
How do I specify CSS code for PDF files I link to?

Comment: Does not necessarily seems to be a new issue, https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=271452 and https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/3511

Comment: _“How do I specify CSS code for PDF files I link to?”_ - I don’t think you can in this instance, this is about the internal workings of the PDF viewer library. I would perhaps first try to lower the CSP settings for resources ending in .pdf, so that at least you can still have to full effect of CSP for your actual HTML documents.